# MATE desktop GUI shows displays only background, unresponsive after waking?

Tags: centos, mate-desktop, remote-desktop

Have been using MATE on CentOS7 (and accessing via Windows RDP Connection Manager) for some time and recently found that after waking the server from sleep, the desktop is blank (only displays the background, no icons or menus) 
[image]
and unresponsive (left/right click does nothing, *but can see and move the mouse on the screen (or at least the mouse changes form when moving it between my host machine screen on the RDP window)*). Not really sure what to make of any of this and can still ssh into the server if more debugging into needed.

*Note, I was not prompted to sign in*. Just seeing a background image (as if the prompt for sign-in is simply failing to popup).

Installed MATE using the article [here](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-install-mate-gui-in-centos-7-linux/) and have system configs as...

```bsh
[root@airflowetl airflow]# systemctl get-default
graphical.target
```

and the user in question has the file...

```bsh
[root@airflowetl airflow]#
cat .Xclients
mate-session
```

set (as per [this](https://draculaservers.com/tutorials/install-xrdp-centos/#2_Install_MATE_Desktop_Environment)) and was working until recently.

Can still navigate to my desktop and homedir when ssh'ing from host

```
[airflow@airflowetl Desktop]$ pwd
/home/airflow/Desktop
[airflow@airflowetl Desktop]$ ls
```

just that nothing shows up in the GUI.

Saw a similar sounding problem [here](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=47271), but 1) MATE uses `caja`, 2) I can't even register clicks within the desktop to open a terminal there, and 3) the post seems to be more related to the desktop files whereas here my desktop is missing even the menu bars.

Anyone with with more experience have any ideas what could be going on? Any debugging advice / ideas on what other info should be added to this post?

Comment: Waking from sleep? Or waking the screensaver? Gnome2/Mate is dependent on the user homedir. Is the user's homedir on an external filesystem? Is it still mounted?

Comment: @Rich "Waking from sleep? Or waking the screensaver?": Not sure the difference, since in either case on the machine, need to sign back in (but just from length of time I was away, I'd say sleep). Homedir is not on an external FS and can still see it when ssh'ing via terminal on host machine.

Comment: After some testing, finding that this problem only occurs with the Gnome desktop, but not when switching to Mate. Need to look more into why.